# How to make two bodies stick after a collision?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, jbox2d

I am really stuck on this I can successfully detect a collision but I can't make the two bodies involved in the collision to stick.

Here is my **ContactListener**

```
world.setContactListener(listener);

    listener = new ContactListener() {

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

        }


        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

        }

        //called when two fixtures cease to touch
        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
            Gdx.app.log("beginContact", "between" + fixtureA.toString() + "and" + fixtureB.toString());
        }

        //called when two fixtures begin to touch
        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
            Gdx.app.log("beginContact", "between" + fixtureA.toString() + "and" + fixtureB.toString());
        }
    };
```

Also this is what I put in my render() straight after the world.step() line

```
int numContacts = world.getContactCount();

    if(numContacts > 0)
    {
        Gdx.app.log("contact", "start of contact list");
        for(Contact contact: world.getContactList())
        {
            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
            Gdx.app.log("contact", "between" + fixtureA.toString() + "and" + fixtureB.toString());
        }
        Gdx.app.log("contact", "end of contact list");
    }
```

I am extremely stuck on what to put on post solve or pre-solve really confused. I followed the iforce2d sticky projectiles http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sticky-projectiles but I don't understand C++ and i get a lot of syntax errors when working in eclipse. Please can someone show me an example code of a working collision where bodies stick together after colliding in java please.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you create a [WeldJoint](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/WeldJoint.html) with the libgdx wrapper:

```
WeldJointDef wd = new WeldJointDef();
wd.bodyA = body1;
wd.bodyB = body2;
wd.referenceAngle = wd.bodyB.getAngle() - wd.bodyA.getAngle();
world.createJoint( wd );
```

Do not try to create Joints inside the ContactListener. Add the bodies to be glued to a list and check them just after **world.step**.

**EDIT:**

Ok, like in the [iforce2d tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sticky-projectiles),create an object to contain 2 bodies:

```
public class StickyInfo{
    Body bodyA;
    Body bodyB;
    public StickyInfo(Body bodyA, Body bodyB){
        this.bodyA = bodyA;
        this.bodyB = bodyB;
    }
};
```

Then create a [libgdx Array](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html) of StickyInfo's

```
Array<StickyInfo> collisionsToMakeSticky = new Array<StickyInfo>();
```

When the bodies collide (well, technically their fixtures), add them to this list:

```
collisionsToMakeSticky.add(new StickyInfo(body1, body2))
```

And then just after **world.step**, if the Array is not empty. Create the WeldJoints:

```
while(collisionsToMakeSticky.size>0){
    StickyInfo si = collisionsToMakeSticky.removeIndex(0);
    //Make the WeldJoint with the bodies si.bodyA and si.bodyB
}
```

Comment: Could you help me on this I've been trying for over a week and I'm still nowhere near it, I know ho to do the weldjoint but I don't know what you mean by adding the bodies to be glued to a list and check them.

Comment: thank you so much this makes a bit more sense now ill try this and let you know if I run into problems, but thank you so much.